# How to solve a Most-Common-Path-like probIem - with Cypher, on a Neo4j graph database

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, path-finding, neo4jrb

We are using neo4j to store academic and professional evolution of many persons (*User*) in order to process and provide the information it contains for our clients.

For example, they may ask for the most frequent professional evolution for people who had a certain diploma (represented as a “*Diploma*” node in the graph database) and worked later in a certain job (a “*Job*” node).

Both *Job* and *Diploma* play a similar role, as a “kind” of step everyone could have on his or her resume (users are not directly linked to them). *Resume* are professional activities who were held by a certain person at a certain period in time: those have one and only one *User* related to them, and also `:CONTAINS` a "*Job_or_Diploma*" to help classifying them.

The *Resume* of a given user are linked to each other by a `:LEADS_TO` relationship, following their succession in time. This succession gives back the whole resume of this user. So we have paths like:

**(u:User)-[:HAS]->(:Resume)-[:LEADS_TO]->(:Resume)<-[:HAS]-(u)**

Thus the problem we need to solve would become : find the most popular path between the *start:Diploma* node and the *end:Job* node, among all paths with "*Job_or_Diploma*" nodes only.

As we define the most common path by properties which do not belong directly to "*Job_or_Diploma*" nodes, and even to any individual node (the 'popularity' of a path depends on the whole path because we measure it by the number of *Users* who followed it completely), we struggle to determine how to find it.

Another pitfall we have to face is that there are actually no direct links between 2 "*Job_or_Diploma*" : a *Resume* `:LEADS_TO` the following *Resume* in the curriculum of the User who `:HAS` them, and each Resume `:CONTAINS` one "*Job_or_Diploma*" of more, but those "*Job_or_Diploma*" have no edge between each other (cf screenshots below). So the path we are looking for doesn't exist in the graph.

**Hence the question : is there a way to find the 'path', or rather 'succession' of "*Job_or_Diploma*" that were taken (in chronological order) by the highest number of *Users* between a certain diploma and a certain job? Ideally, we look for something that we could implement using Cypher only.**

We would be glad to receive any insight to show us how to proceed. Below are a few screens of some parts of our graph which are implied in this problem:

[The kind of configuration we are dealing with in this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keXqM.png)

[2 users' *Resumes* between a diploma in Engineering and a position in Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMKXc.png)

[4 users' length-2 *Resume* paths between a diploma in Engineering and a Technical Director position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIESh.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since a node can have multiple labels, your `Resume` nodes can also have either a `Diploma` or `Job` label. There is no need to have separate nodes with `Diploma` or `Job` labels.

So, you can simplify your data model to, for example:

```
(u:User)-[:HAS]->(:Resume:Diploma)-[:LEADS_TO]->(:Resume:Job)<-[:HAS]-(u)
```

And finding all paths that start with an "Engineering" degree and end at a "Management" job would be this simple:

```
MATCH path=(u:User)-[:HAS]->(:Diploma {type: 'Engineering'})-[:LEADS_TO*]->(:Job {type: 'Management'})
RETURN path;
```

In addition, you may have no real reason to have a `Resume` label at all (e.g., the above query does not use it), so you could further simplify your data model to just have the `Diploma` and `Job` labels.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it would be much simpler. However, we didn't imagine we could change our model, because it seems we need that distinction between `Resume` (which belong to one user) and `ResumeNode` (the actual label for "Job_or_Diploma" nodes in our database, which stand for a 'generic' carreer step - eg, "Directeur Technique" on the screenshots of the post) : For example, without it, we don't know how to get all the multiple jobs a user have done in one enterprise, or how to access all the locations related to his resume.But if you do, we d be grateful to you to sharing some hints with us!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, a `Job` node could have a "title" property for things like "Directeur Technique" -- or a relationship to a `Title` node. And each `Diploma` or `Job` node could have an `AT` relationship to a `Company` or `School` node.